# Python: Access mesh selection history data

Tags: python, bmesh

I want to write an addon that can combine two selections with a logical AND.

For example, the user use via normal gui

```
bpy.ops.mesh.select_similar(type='LENGTH')
```

and

```
bpy.ops.mesh.select_similar(type='DIR').
```

Then he calls the addon, the addon gets the current selection, the selection made before, combine them and write the selection back.

My problem is I don't know how I can access these history data via python nor if it's possible. This would be my favorite way of workflow for the addon.

I can extend the addon with a call to store the actual selection, so the user make a similar select, call the addon to store the current selection, make another similar select and call the addon to combine the both selections and write it back.

For this way I need to store a customized boolean at the bmesh faces/edges/vertices data, but I can't figure it out how. If I try to store custom data I run in these error:

> bm.faces[0]['and_select'] = False
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in 
>   AttributeError: BMElem[key]: invalid key, must be a BMLayerItem

An example how this must be done would help.

Comment: I don't see a purpose for your intended addon. If you use select similar in the UI, the current selection will be extended. There's really no need to "combine" selections by script.

Comment: I don´t want to extend the selection, i want the intersection of two different selections. Such as do a binary AND operation.

Comment: I see, check out my addon [border deselect outer](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/BAC/browse/master/mesh_border_deselect_outer.py) then. I recommend pink vertex's solution however for your particular problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use the string key. Instead use [a direct reference for the layer](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_72_1/bmesh.html#customdata-access):

```
layer = bm.faces.layers.int.new('layer_name')
bm.faces[0][layer] = 0
```

There is [no boolean layer available](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_72_1/bmesh.types.html#bmesh.types.BMLayerAccessFace).

The [selection history](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_72_1/bmesh.types.html#bmesh.types.BMEditSelSeq) works only for single verts/edges/faces.

You can use the [bmesh operators](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_72_1/bmesh.ops.html#bmesh.ops.similar_faces) `similar_faces`, `similar_edges`, `similar_verts` which will return the selection.

Links to the source: [bmo_similar.c](http://git.blender.org/gitweb/gitweb.cgi/blender.git/blob/HEAD:/source/blender/bmesh/operators/bmo_similar.c), [`bmesh_operators.h`](http://git.blender.org/gitweb/gitweb.cgi/blender.git/blob/HEAD:/source/blender/bmesh/intern/bmesh_operators.h)